# Active NameNode is killed when trying to perform $ hdfs dfs -mkdir /app

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

find the below logs from active NN
using **oc** ( openshift console cli equivalent to **kubectl** )

```
$ oc exec -it apache-hadoop-namenode-0 -c namenode -- bash

$ hdfs dfs  -mkdir /app
WARNING: HADOOP_PREFIX has been replaced by HADOOP_HOME. Using value of HADOOP_PREFIX.
{"name":"org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler","time":1661110979165,"date":"2022-08-21 19:42:59,165","level":"INFO","thread":"main","message":"java.io.EOFException: End of File Exception between local host is: \"apache-hadoop-namenode-0.apache-hadoop-namenode.nom-backend.svc.cluster.local/10.128.3.182\"; destination host is: \"apache-hadoop-namenode-0.apache-hadoop-namenode.nom-backend.svc.cluster.local\":8020; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException, while invoking ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs over apache-hadoop-namenode-0.apache-hadoop-namenode.nom-backend.svc.cluster.local/10.128.3.182:8020. Trying to failover immediately."}{"name":"org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler","time":1661110979206,"date":"2022-08-21 19:42:59,206","level":"INFO","thread":"main","message":"org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category WRITE is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.StandbyState.checkOperation(StandbyState.java:108)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$NameNodeHAContext.checkOperation(NameNode.java:2094)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkOperation(FSNamesystem.java:1550)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3397)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1159)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:740)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:604)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:572)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:556)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1093)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1043)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:971)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2976)\n, while invoking ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs over apache-hadoop-namenode-1.apache-hadoop-namenode.nom-backend.svc.cluster.local/10.131.0.246:8020 after 1 failover attempts. Trying to failover after sleeping for 830ms."}{"name":"org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler","time":1661110980038,"date":"2022-08-21 19:43:00,038","level":"INFO","thread":"main","message":"java.net.ConnectException: Call From apache-hadoop-namenode-0.apache-hadoop-namenode.nom-backend.svc.cluster.local/10.128.3.182 to apache-hadoop-namenode-0.apache-hadoop-namenode.nom-backend.svc.cluster.local:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused, while invoking ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs over apache-hadoop-namenode-0.apache-hadoop-namenode.nom-backend.svc.cluster.local/10.128.3.182:8020 after 2 failover attempts. Trying to failover after sleeping for 2255ms."}
```

Comment: this was the active NN, and after executing that command -mkdir , this active NN is killed

Comment: i had given rpc address as hdfs://${POD_NAME}-0:8020 . after removing hdfs:// seems to resolve this issue.